# Cannot convert value of type [Any]! to type 'MySpecificClass' in coercion: in Swift3 while using for in loop

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using RDVTabBarController in my project and trying to customise the tab bar controller by using for in loop and It's not convert as RDVTabBarItem class getting error.

```
for item in tabBarController.tabBar.items as RDVTabBarItem {
            //
        }
```

Comment: You want `for item abBarController.tabBar.items as [RDVTabBarItem]` - `items` is an array and Swift is telling you that you can't cast an array to a single object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means *Cannot convert value of type **Array** to a **single** 
item* and you actually want an array:

```
for item in tabBarController.tabBar.items as [RDVTabBarItem] { ...
```